# signal 6 during sqlite3 step

Tags: linux, sqlite

Working on WAL mode - a single writer and multiple readers.
Readers are threads in the same process, using serialise mode.

Here is the backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007f4f78f0d08d in nanosleep () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f4f78f0cf2c in sleep () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f4f7982d881 in signal_catch (signo=6) at signal_masker.c:35
#3  <signal handler called>
#4  0x00007f4f78e83425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007f4f78e86b8b in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#6  0x00007f4f78ec139e in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#7  0x00007f4f78ecbb96 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#8  0x00007f4f77661690 in sqlite3_free () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0
#9  0x00007f4f77664b96 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0
#10 0x00007f4f77664c7c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0
#11 0x00007f4f77664cb0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0
#12 0x00007f4f7768b477 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0
#13 0x00007f4f7769a249 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0
#14 0x00007f4f776a9689 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0
#15 0x00007f4f776ae451 in sqlite3_step () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.s
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: This looks like memory corruption, which is likely to be caused by your code.

Comment: Since WAL mode uses shared mem, it might be related to this. This error occurs randomly with the same code, so I find it hard to believe it is related to the code. I have checked that the allocations are correct (otherwise I would get segmentation fault).